# Iterative optimization of alternative glm family

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, optimization

I'm setting up an alternative response function to the commonly used exponential function in poisson glms, which is called softplus and defined as $\frac{1}{c} \log(1+\exp(c \eta))$, where $\eta$ corresponds to the linear predictor $X\beta$.

NOW I have to find a way to optimize the usual regression coefficients $\beta$
and the additional parameter $c$ of this new response function simultaneously and don't know how to solve it. (So I'm not asking for code review but theoretical suggestions how to manage this kind of iterative/simultaneous optimization)

I tried to write a log-lik function, score function and then setting up a Newton Raphson optimization (using a while loop) but I don't know how to seperate the updating of $c$ in an outer step and updating $\beta$ in an inner step..

Are there any suggestions? Is this procedure wrong?

```
# Response function:
sp <- function(eta, c = 1 ) {  
  return(log(1 + exp(abs(c * eta)))/ c) 
} 

# Log Likelihood
l.lpois <- function(par, y, X){
  beta <- par[1:(length(par)-1)]
  c <- par[length(par)]
  l <- rep(NA, times = length(y))
  for (i in 1:length(l)){
    l[i] <- y[i] * log(sp(X[i,]%*%beta, c)) - sp(X[i,]%*%beta, c) 
  }
  l <- sum(l)
  return(l)
}

# Score function
score <- function(y, X, par){
  beta <- par[1:(length(par)-1)]
  c <- par[length(par)]

  s <- matrix(rep(NA, times = length(y)*length(par)), ncol = length(y))
  for (i in 1:length(y)){
    s[,i] <- c(X[i,], 1) * (y[i] * plogis(c * X[i,]%*%beta) / sp(X[i,]%*%beta, c) -     plogis(c * X[i,]%*%beta))
  }
  score <- rep(NA, times = nrow(s))
  for (j in 1:length(score)){
    score[j] <- sum(s[j,])
  }
  return(score)
}

# Optimization function
opt <- function(y, X, b.start, eps=0.0001, maxiter = 1e5){
  beta <- b.start[1:(length(b.start)-1)]
  c <- b.start[length(b.start)]

  b.old <- b.start
  i <- 0
  conv <- FALSE

  while(conv == FALSE){ 

    eta <- X%*%b.old[1:(length(b.old)-1)]
    s <- score(y, X, b.old)
    h <- numDeriv::hessian(l.lpois,b.old,y=y,X=X)

    invh <- solve(h)

    # update 
    b.new <- b.old + invh %*% s                                                         

    i <- i + 1

    # Test 
    if(any(is.nan(b.new))){                                                             
      b.new <- b.old                                                                
      warning("convergence failed")
      break 
    } 

    # convergence reached?
    if(sqrt(sum((b.new - b.old)^2))/sqrt(sum(b.old^2)) < eps | i >= maxiter){ 
      conv <- TRUE
    }
    b.old <- b.new
  }
  eta <- X%*%b.new[1:(length(b.new)-1)]

  # covariance
  invh  <- solve(numDeriv::hessian(l.lpois,b.new,y=y,X=X)) 


  fitted <- sp(eta, b.new[length(b.new)])

  result <- list("coefficients" = c(beta = b.new),
                 "fitted.values" = fitted,
                 "covariance" = invh)
}

# convergence fails ..
n <- 100
x <- runif(n, 0, 1)
Xdes <- cbind(1, x) 
eta <- 1 + 2 * x
y <- rpois(n, sp(eta, c = 1))



opt(y,Xdes,c(0,1,1))
```

Comment: Could you describe the problem in words? What is your question? If you are looking for code review, this may not be the best place.

Comment: I have to find a way to optimize the usual regression coefficitents $\beta$ and the additional parameter $c$ of this new response function simultaneously and don't know how to solve it.
So I'm not asking for code review but theoretical suggestions how to manage this kind of iterative/simultaneous optimization

Comment: Ok, could you edit your question adding this?

Answer (score 3):

**Parametric link functions**

The "softplus" model you have proposed is called a *parametric link function* in generalized linear model theory. Technically, the link function is the inverse of your softplus function.

I can think of three major ways to estimate parametric link functions.
I'll list them in decreasing order of computational speed and programming difficulty.

**Nested Fisher scoring**

Mathematical algorithms to estimate parametric link functions have been given by Scallan et al (1984) and Smyth (1996). In Example 4.4 of Smyth (1996), I gave a very efficient algorithm for estimating the linear predictor parameters (your $\beta$) in an inner loop and the link parameter (your $c$) in an outer loop.
The idea of inner and outer loops is called *nested iterations* in my paper and my algorithm is called *nested Fisher scoring*.

**Generalized nonlinear models**

Parametric link functions are a special case of the larger class of *Generalized nonlinear models* (GNMs).
You will find a number of publications on that topic if you do a Google Scholar search.
Rather than programming a super-efficient algorithm, for which you really do need to be an R expert, you might find it simpler to use the `gnm` package on CRAN, which provides a code approach for GNMs.

**Profile likelihood**

The third way to estimate $c$ is take a profile likelihood approach.
For each fixed values of $c$ you have an ordinary GLM with a nonstandard link function.
For given $c$, fit the GLM and compute the log-likelihood or AIC.
As a function of $c$, this called a *profile likelihood*.
You can then use the `optimize` function in R to maximize the profile likelihood with respect to the single parameter $c$.

You can implement the GLM fit using R's built-in `glm` function.
Just copy the `poisson(link="log")` family and edit the link and link derivative entries to be appropriate for your softplus function.
Then you can specify your own softplus link when you run `glm`.

All of these approach are much better than trying to work with numerical derivatives.

**References**

Scallan, A., Gilchrist, R. and Green, M. (1984). Fitting parametric link functions
in generalised linear models. *Comput. Statist. Data Anal.*, 2, 37–49.

Smyth, G. K. (1996). Partitioned algorithms for maximum likelihood and other nonlinear estimation. *Statistics and Computing*, 6, 201–216.
http://www.statsci.org/smyth/pubs/partitio.pdf

Comment: thank u sir!!! 
The profile likelihood approach can then be solved using a while loop, right?

Comment: @Parastoo The profile likelihood method I outlined does not need any loop at all. You just make a single call to `optimize`.